# Basic PHP search...in need of reset script

Tags: php, forms, search

I'm **very** new to PHP, so bear with my ignorance. I've got the following script that searches an excel sheet for cell data (it's a really basic company phonebook):

```
    <html>
<?php echo "Search:" ?>
<form id="form1" method="post" action ="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>"> <label>
<input id="search" name="search" type="text" />
</label>
<label>
<input type="submit" />
</label>
<img src="loading.gif" width="16" height="11" />
</form>
<input type="reset" value="Reset">
<?php
$search= $_REQUEST['search'];
if ($search > ''){ $search = $search;} else { $search = '';}
?>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
google.load('visualization', '1', {packages: ['table']});
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
var visualization;

function drawVisualization() {

var query = new google.visualization.Query(
'https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/pub?key=0Ap2dozrbYI5vdEV5ZmtzU3hCdktzWDU0NTdOQjRSNkE&single=true&gid=0&output=html');

query.setQuery('SELECT A, B, C, D where upper(A) like upper("%<?php echo $search; ?>%") or upper(B) like upper("%<?php echo $search; ?>%") order by A asc label A "Company", B "Contact Name", C "Contact Number", D "Company General Contact"');

query.send(handleQueryResponse);
}

function handleQueryResponse(response) {
if (response.isError()) {
alert('Error in query: ' + response.getMessage() + ' ' + response.getDetailedMessage());
return;
}

var data = response.getDataTable();

visualization = new google.visualization.Table(document.getElementById('table'));
visualization.draw(data, {legend: 'bottom'});

    }

    google.setOnLoadCallback(drawVisualization);
    </script>

    <div id="table"></div>

    </div>
    </html>
```

When no text is entered and the user clicks submit, the view resets to show the complete excel sheet. I'd like to add a reset button that functions the same way (it makes more sense to the user to have an actual "reset" button.

Edit: Just a note that I'm **not** trying to simply clear the search input. Essentially, I'd like to replicate what the submit button does when a blank search is performed (which is display all the data).

Comment: I am just curious - what exactly code `{ $search = $search; }` does?

Comment: well, couldn't you have a "reset labeled button" and just check to see if it is set in post? `if(isset($_POST['reset']))`

Comment: I didn't include the rest of the script, but this pulls data from a Google docs spreadsheet through their Java API:

`<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
google.load('visualization', '1', {packages: ['table']});
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
var visualization;

function drawVisualization() {

var query = new google.visualization.Query(`

Comment: @mgiljum you can edit your original post and add that to your post. Kinda sloppy in comments :P

Comment: Sorry XD I'm new. I actually changed it to include the entire script

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a number of issues here that need to be addressed.  I've cleaned out some of the code you posted but I didn't want to totally rewrite everything you did.  It looks like you might have copied and pasted a couple examples you found on the web into one project.  It really helps if you review what a script does before you put it into production.  Doing so will help you with some of these issues.  For instance, in one line you check a variable to see if it is greater than empty string.  You then assign it to itself if it is and you assign it to empty string if it is empty.  Basically, that line does nothing.  Read through your code so you know what it does.

In the end, I figured out that you didn't really need PHP for anything.  You are simply using it to post back to the server and reload the page.  Since you are using JavaScript to actually load your information, I decided to do everything in JavaScript.  It makes the page simpler and it prevents unnecessary postbacks.  I also formatted your code a bit and cleaned it up some.  However, this still needs to be further refined and cleaned up.  I just got it to a working state:

```
<html>
    <body>
        <input id="search" name="search" type="text" />
        <button id="submitQuery">Submit Query</button>
        <button id="resetQuery">Reset Query</button>
        <div id="table"></div>

        <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            google.load('visualization', '1', { packages: ['table'] });

            var visualization;
            var searchTerm = '';

            function drawVisualization() {
                var query = new google.visualization.Query(
                'https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/pub?key=0Ap2dozrbYI5vdEV5ZmtzU3hCdktzWDU0NTdOQjRSNkE&single=true&gid=0&output=html');
                query.setQuery('SELECT A, B, C, D where upper(A) like upper("%' + searchTerm + '%") or upper(B) like upper("%' + searchTerm + '%") order by A asc label A "Company", B "Contact Name", C "Contact Number", D "Company General Contact"');
                query.send(handleQueryResponse);
            }

            function handleQueryResponse(response) {
                if (response.isError()) {
                    alert('Error in query: ' + response.getMessage() + ' ' + response.getDetailedMessage());
                    return;
                }

                var data = response.getDataTable();

                visualization = new google.visualization.Table(document.getElementById('table'));
                visualization.draw(data, { legend: 'bottom' });
            }

            google.setOnLoadCallback(drawVisualization);

            $(function () {
                $('#submitQuery').click(function (e) {
                    searchTerm = $('#search').val();
                    drawVisualization();
                    return false;
                });
                $('#resetQuery').click(function (e) {
                    $('#search').val('');
                    searchTerm = '';
                    drawVisualization();
                    return false;
                });
            });
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Instead of using buttons in a form to do a postback, I made the buttons fill in the variable appropriately and call the function to draw the visualization.   I did draw in jQuery to make things a bit easier (note the call to the CDN for it).  That made the code cleaner and easier to use.  You don't have to do it that way but you will need to rework my code if you take it out.

Let me know if you have any questions.  As it stands now, this code should do exactly what you want it to do.

Comment: Debugging shows error on line 37 - "$ is undefined" - `$(function () {`

Comment: You aren't actually calling the drawVisualization() in PHP - you always called it in JavaScript (even in your original version).  The only thing that PHP did for you was to put the value of the search box in the JavaScript string.  As for the debugging error of $ is undefined, that means that the jQuery library isn't being loaded.  If you have the library loading from the CDN, it is being blocked (which it shouldn't be).  If you replaced it with the local version, you didn't include it properly.

Comment: Working now, was a security issue on the web server. Guess I should remember my own security policies XD Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

Add this line to your html form:

```
<input type="reset" value="Reset">
```

Comment: I agree, i'd seperate html and php

Comment: @roguequery Adding `<input type="reset" value="Reset">` does nothing, both when inside the `<form>` and outside.

Comment: @Peter I get the following string that shows in plain text after the Reset button: `''){ $search = $search;} else { $search = '';} ?>`

Comment: Try removing this line:if ($search > ''){ $search = $search;} else { $search = '';}